# How to detect when anchor is clicked and add extra pixels and keep URL

Tags: jquery

Because I have a fixed position header, when anchor links are clicked some of the content is obscured by the header, so I want to modify the position so that the requested content is completely visible. I am presently doing this successfully with the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[href^='#']").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        var newPosition = $(id).offset();
        if (newPosition != undefined) {
            window.scrollTo(newPosition.left, newPosition.top - 50);
        }
        else {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

However the problem with this method is that the URL never changes to add the #anchor part so users cannot bookmark the page as I would want them to.

Is there a way of doing this where the URL will change? I need wide browser compatability so I don't think I can change the URL. I was thinking I could perhaps monitor the window scroll event and see if the URL hash has changed and if so do the 50 pixel adjustment. But is there a better way?

Comment: in your callback try use event.preventDefault(), where event - first attribute of your callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To possible answer my own question, I have experimented with a script that does what is needed and works when the page is opened with a hash, when you click a hash, when you click the same hash after scrolling, and also handles the back button. This seems to work in popular browsers.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var scrollOnReady = false;
            var lastHash = window.location.hash ? window.location.hash : "";
            if (lastHash != "") {
                scrollOnReady = true;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var newPosition = $(lastHash).offset();
                    if (newPosition != undefined) {
                        if ($(window).scrollTop() == newPosition.top) {
                            window.scrollTo(newPosition.left, newPosition.top - 50);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    }
                }, 50);
            }

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if (scrollOnReady) {
                    scrollOnReady = false;
                }
                else {
                    if ((window.location.hash ? window.location.hash : "") !== lastHash) {
                        lastHash = window.location.hash ? window.location.hash : "";
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 50);
                        }, 50);
                    }
                }
            });

            $("a[href^='#']").click(function () {
                var hash = $(this).attr("href");
                if (hash === lastHash) {
                    lastHash = "";
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a complex problem.  There is an excellent plugin designed especially to solve this problem called [BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/).  One issue (which you might not have realized will be an issue yet) is the use of the back button.  Users expect the back button to "take" them to the last place before they clicked a link.  If you don't support that you will have very sad users.  BBQ is able to solve these issues and make the back button work correctly.

Comment: Does the document ready event fire if the back button is clicked because I could check for a hash value there and do my position change then?

Comment: @John - I'm telling you BBQ is the way to go.  It is different on every browser how these things work.